# Android ListView - how to display

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, android-activity

i would like to display items in my ListView as per image below.

[image: An entry in the listview]

- The square on the left is an image
- The rectangles on the right are text boxes

**Questions:**

- What should my XML look like?
- How do I insert the items there?

**Current code:**

Layout:

activity_news_feed.xml

```
<ListView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/newsfeed"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

list_single.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
    android:padding="6dip" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/icon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="6dip"
        android:contentDescription="TODO"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/secondLine"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="26dip"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/icon"
        android:ellipsize="marquee"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text="Description"
        android:textSize="12sp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@id/secondLine"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignWithParentIfMissing="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/icon"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text="Example application"
        android:textSize="16sp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Activity:

```
package uk.ac.gla.serengeti.activities;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

import uk.ac.gla.serengeti.R;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class NewsFeed extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_news_feed);
            // Show the Up button in the action bar.
            setupActionBar();

            final ListView listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.newsfeed);

            String[] values = new String[] { "Android", "iPhone", "WindowsMobile",
                    "Blackberry", "WebOS", "Ubuntu", "Windows7", "Max OS X",
                    "Linux", "OS/2", "Ubuntu", "Windows7", "Max OS X", "Linux",
                    "OS/2", "Ubuntu", "Windows7", "Max OS X", "Linux", "OS/2",
                    "Android", "iPhone", "WindowsMobile" };

            final ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
            for (int i = 0; i < values.length; ++i) {
              list.add(values[i]);
            }
            final StableArrayAdapter adapter = new StableArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list);
            listview.setAdapter(adapter);

            listview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
                  @Override
                  public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                      "Click ListItem Number " + position, Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                      .show();
                  }
                });           
    }

    private void setupActionBar() {
            ActionBar actionBar = this.getSupportActionBar();
            actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);            
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.news_feed, menu);
            return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case android.R.id.home:
                    // This ID represents the Home or Up button. In the case of this
                    // activity, the Up button is shown. Use NavUtils to allow users
                    // to navigate up one level in the application structure. For
                    // more details, see the Navigation pattern on Android Design:
                    //
                    // http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation.html#up-vs-back
                    //
                    //NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
                    finish();
                    return true;
            }
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    private class StableArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

        HashMap<String, Integer> mIdMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

        public StableArrayAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,
            List<String> objects) {
          super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);
          for (int i = 0; i < objects.size(); ++i) {
            mIdMap.put(objects.get(i), i);
          }
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
          String item = getItem(position);
          return mIdMap.get(item);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean hasStableIds() {
          return true;
        }

      }
}
```

Comment: I found the best solution [Android ListView - Tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html) that you want May **[THIS LINK](http://www.learn2crack.com/2013/10/android-custom-listview-images-text-example.html)** also helpful to you.

Answer (score 3):

1. Create the layout of the row in an xml file.

It should look something like this. You might need to change the layout weights:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
    android:padding="6dip" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/icon"
        android:layout_width="70dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLEft="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="6dip"
        android:contentDescription="TODO"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/secondLine"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/icon"
        android:ellipsize="marquee"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text="Description"
        android:textSize="12sp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@id/secondLine"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignWithParentIfMissing="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/icon"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text="Example application"
        android:textSize="16sp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

1. Create a customer Adapter of your listview which extends `BaseAdapter`
2. Override the getView() method of BaseAdapter; expand the layout and set the data in the Views according to the position.

   public View getView ( int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent )
       {
           LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
           convertView = inflater.inflate ( R.layout.recipe_row, null );

   ```
       ImageView image = ( ImageView ) convertView.findViewById ( R.id.image );
       TextView title = ( TextView ) convertView.findViewById ( R.id.title );
       TextView description = ( TextView ) convertView.findViewById ( R.id.description );

       Recipe recipe = this.getItem ( position );
       image.setImageBitmap(recipte.getBitmap());
       title.setText(recipe.getTitle());
       description.setText(recipe.getDescription());

       return convertView;
   }
   ```

Comment: I am struggling with the layout :)

Comment: Sure, please paste your XML

Comment: I updated the code. I am unsure when and where should i inflate the list_single layout.

Comment: Your XML does not have a root element. All XML Files must have a root e.g. the first LinearLayout in the XML in my answer. Second,You should override the getView method of your `StableArrayAdapter` and this is where you should inflate your list_single layout.

Comment: i just edited the code. For some reason Stack Overflow cut off a bit of the XML code. Have a look now.

Comment: I updated the XML in my answer. Check that it works. My guess is that you gave the image a size of `wrap_content` and so it takes up a lot od space and doesn't leave room for the other views.

Comment: What is inflater? convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_single);

Comment: Also, what is holder and resultview? Could you tailor the code to my problem?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46626/discussion-between-martynas-and-w-k-s)

Comment: I can't chat cuz i'm at work but i've corrected my getView() code.